# Thunderbird 3, must manually re-build folder index

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have a couple of installations of thunbderbird three that aren't updating the IMAP folders correctly. I have to manually re-build index of the foldres for it to refresh.

any ideas how to fix this problem? Im not using synchornishing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded to Thunderbird 3.0.3?

I was experiencing indexing issues (messages marked as unread when they were read) with earlier versions of Thunderbird 3 (Mac version).  The indexing issues seem to have gone away in 3.0.3.